Having difficulty figuring out how to read lines of hex from a file and convert to ascii then output to text file
Edit for clarity: I extracted the code from my arduino. It's currently all in hex.
For context; I have an arduino project code from last semester and have been starting to explore python. I extracted the code from the arduino and now I'm trying to convert the hex code from the arduino into ascii so I can just have my code back.
I've only got some experience with C++. The code that I'm translating will look something along the lines of:
:20 00E0 00 AC35B107D9F722E0ACE5B1E001C01D92A433B207E1F710E0C2E6D0E004C02197 D7
On Notepad++ the 20 is the start code, the 00E0 is the address, and the last 00 is brown(record type?), then the D7 is the byte count. The big string in the middle is black. I'm assuming that everything except the big long string can be discarded since I pulled this from my Arduino memory.
The playbook I've followed so far:

Open the file with the hex code in it
Read the file with the hex code into a temp file
Convert the text in the temp file from hex to binary to ascii, or just hex to ascii
Write the lines in the temp file into the actual output file

My code:
from math import ceil
import binascii
import tempfile
import os

# open the thing
f = open(" ", "r")

# read the thing
with open(os.path.abspath(f.name), 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    hexLines = []
    for item in lines:
        hexLines.append(item.encode('utf-8').hex)
        binascii.unhexlify(hexLines)


# convert the thing
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
    print(hexLines)

# Write thing
g = open(" ", "w")
g.write('r')


Confusing. "I extracted the code from the Arduino" What code? The executable machine code? Are you trying to disassemble it? Or is it some data you want to parse?

The code has already been extracted from my arduino. It's the C++ based code but currently in hexidecimal form. Or encoded in hexidecimal. I'm not sure what the right terminology is.

D7 is 215 decimal, that's not 215 bytes of data though. What do you mean by "D7 is the byte count"? And what do you mean by "The big string in the middle is black" ? Also, you say you want to convert to ascii, but then you're encoding to UTF-8?

Sorry. I'm still learning the right way to work through questions on here.
I was breaking down the formatting of the hex code in notepad++ which is color coding it based on the intel hex in notepad++.
Ultimately what I'm hoping to do is take this from being what it is currently and change the hex into text/code that I can then play around with again. I pulled the code off the arduino from it's memory using another utility and now I'm trying to come up with a script to turn the list of hex into a list of ascii characters.
